# Hawkbit creating rollout through API

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I referred this https://stefbehl.github.io/hawkbit-101/#/34 link to create the hawkbit rollout api but its giving the error like "body content not in well format".

so, can anyone help me what to give in body content while creating the rollout api through postman.